# Add a custom tag to an url in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurl, custom-tag

It's Julian Again. In my project I have around 50 different urls and i need to group them into two groups. So that 25 of them are displayed in VC one and the rest in VC2. I wanted to add a tag, and then based on this tag distinguish the two groups but I don't know how to do that. 
So that it looks like that:

```
NSURL tag:@"a"
```

and then

```
if(tag == "a")
{// Do the code}
```

How could I do that Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you mean by tag ? From where do you get those urls ? On what basis you need to set the tag in your code ?

Comment: Okay. to be precise, all of them are links to url's. I have to display some in Portrait and some in landscape. That's why i have to distinguish them.

Comment: My question is how you are identifying which all are used to be in portrait and which all are used in landscape ? From where you get that information (if you need to add tag also, you need that information right ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either using `NSDictionary` or `NSObject` to store your URL instance and the associated tag value.  I would prefer using `NSObject`:

Create a subclass of `NSObject` called `MyNSURLObject`.

For `MyNSURLObject.h`:  (you don't need to modify `MyNSURLObject.m` file)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyNSURLObject : NSObject
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSURL *myURL;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *myTag;
@end
```

Create an instance of MyNSURLObject whenever you need to store an URL, ex:

```
MyNSURLObject *myNSURLObject = [[MyNSURLObject alloc] init];
myNSURLObject.myURL = whateverurl;
myNSURLObject.myTag = @"a"; // or @"b"
```

Comment: Then I create that in the gallery view controller and make it object 1 then 2 then 3, right?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Do I create an object for every url i have?

Comment: Yes and instead of carrying the list ( or however you have handled) of URLs before, now you keep the list of this object.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 25 urls in one array (Swift `Array` or Objective-C `NSMutableArray`) and 25 in another. Arrays allow you to group 'values' in unique containers.

Then pass the first array to the first view controller and same with the second array.